# Do blade elseif conditionals end if the first condition is met

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I have an elseif in blade that looks like below:

```
@if(condition 1)
    Something 1
@elseif(condition 2)
    Something 2
@else
    Something 3
@endif
```

If the first condition is met and the Something 1 happens, will the statement completely end, or will it also hit something 2, assuming condition 2 is met

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The body of the first condition will execute and then it will end.
If you want to check for condition 2 as well then you need to make it also an if outside of that if else if series.

Answer (score 0):

If else statement statement execute different for more than two conditions in your code it will be like this:

```
@if (condition 1)
    code to be executed only if this condition 1 is true;
@elseif (condition 2)
     code to be executed only if this condition 2 is true and condition 1 is false;
@else
     code to be executed if all conditions are false;
@endif
```

You can learn more at [php if else w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_if_else.asp) it is similar to laravel blade template.